# How to use NestJS Versioning with Router module

Tags: node.js, nestjs

In our nest 8 project we use the RouterModule for routing between different parts of the app:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.register([
      {
        path: '/internal',
        module: InternalModule
      },
      {
        path: '/external',
        module: ExternalModule
      }
    ]),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

In the InternalModule we would like to use [NestJS versioning](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/versioning):

```
@Controller('someroute')
export class InternalController {
  @Get(':id')
  @Version(['1'])
  async getPerson(@Param('id') id): Promise<any> {}
}
```

Routing without versioning works, versioning without routing too, but the combination does not.
I tried calling it via "localhost:port/v1/internal/someroute" and "localhost:port/internal/v1/someroute"

Versioning is enabled:

```
app.enableVersioning({
  type: VersioningType.URI
});
```